# preg_match() fails silently while checking a very long string

Tags: php, zend-framework, preg-match

I am using Zend Framework in one of my projects and the file Zend/Uri/Http.php has a function validateQuery which validates a given query using preg_match.

It works fine normally but I have a paypal url query string which is very long, around 1 500 Characters, and the `preg_match` function fails silently for this query.

I am using PHP ver. 5.4.7 hence I don't have the limit of pcre.backtrack_limit=100000.

Right now I have modified the file in Zendframework to not validate any queries above 1000 characters but this obviously isn't the right solution.

Following one of comments I tried to use another very long query with preg_match in a standalone page and I have the same error, I am pasting my test data below for reference.

```
$query = 'search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&search?q=very+long+query+string+example&aq=f&oq=very+long+query+string+example&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5553j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8';

$pattern = "/^(?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\];\/?:@&=+$,])*$/";

echo preg_match( $pattern, $query );
```

Comment: maybe there is a timeout...

Comment: You should report this problem to Zend, not (only) here. Because the normal procedure is to discuss the problem with the software vendor and fix it there.

Comment: If you just run the `preg_match()` all on its own, outside of ZF, do you have the same problem? If so can you edit your question to include  that example?

Comment: I have just tried pregmatch in a standalone php page but with my query, and its the same result, it fails. but it works fine with shorter queries.

Comment: Your example returns 1 for me using PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2. Can you check whether the return value for you is 0 (no match), or false (error)? Also check the Apache error log for PHP errors or a segmentation fault. Does look like a bug in PHP (not ZF) though.

Comment: It works as it should: `preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.` You need to assign the return to a variable (`$matches`)

Comment: @Tim, I have a windows machine with PHP 5.4.7 and it doesn't return me anything, it just fails and no output is returned to the browser at all

Comment: That sounds like a segfault - does anything get added to the Apache error log?

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I have modified the file in Zendframework to not validate any queries above 1000 characters but this obviously isn't the right solution.

Well, this does not sound *too* wrong to me. 1000 characters sounds like a sane limit to allow URL input and to deny everything larger than that. Also large URLs seem to exploit the validator, therefore I would really filter them out until the software vendor has fixed this flaw in their library.

Check the vendor for your support options for the case you've found a potential bug or flaw. As this is related to validation and has security implications I'm pretty sure the vendor will be happy to learn about the problem.

Comment: I think that is a bad solution because I shouldn't be modifying the framework's core files unless it really is a problem there and can't be fixed by something in my own code. But yes if there is a problem in the framework of an unforeseen issue then it seems good to fix it in their code

Comment: Yes, you should really report this problem. Provide them samples so they can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also see the comment of *Tim Fountain*, isolate the problem and add the isolated demo to your question. That will give you more feedback here on SO.